# How to write a for loop from specific row?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to predict the premiere league. I am using moving average for getting the new season's team home shot, away shot and fouls. I wrote a function for moving average but I am not able to put it in a for loop so that it can utilize the function to auto populate those columns. I tried but it is not working.

```
def get_avg_stats_last_n_games(team, game_date, n):
    prev_game_df = (
        prem_league[prem_league["Date"] < game_date][
            (prem_league["HomeTeam"] == team)
            | (prem_league["AwayTeam"] == team)
        ]
        .sort_values(by="Date")
        .tail(n)
    )

    h_df = prev_game_df.iloc[:, range(2, 20, 2)]
    h_df.columns = [
        "Team",
        "Fulltime G",
        "Halftime G",
        "shots",
        "shots on target",
        "foul",
        "corner",
        "yellow",
        "red",
    ]
    a_df = prev_game_df.iloc[:, range(3, 21, 2)]
    a_df.columns = [
        "Team",
        "Fulltime G",
        "Halftime G",
        "shots",
        "shots on target",
        "foul",
        "corner",
        "yellow",
        "red",
    ]

    df = pd.concat([h_df, a_df])
    df = df[df["Team"] == team]
    df.drop(columns=["Team"], inplace=True)

    return df.mean().round()
```

this is the for loop for auto populating the table with the help of moving average from the row I want to predict the shots, foul and others:

```
for index, row in prem_league4.iloc[3840:].iterrows():
    
    game_date = row['Date']
    h_team = row['HomeTeam']
    a_team = row['AwayTeam']
    
    aa = get_avg_stats_last_n_games(a_team, game_date, 20)
    prem_league4['AS'] = aa[4]
```

can someone help me write the loop?

[The table that I want to populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKByi.png).

I want to fill the NA's in this table with the function I create for that I was trying to use for loop but I am not able to figure out how to do it. The table is filled till the row 3839 and I want to start the for loop from row number 3840 and populate the home and away shots with moving average function in the for loop.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you please provide some example inputs and expected output you would want to get, to get a better understanding of what your goal is? Thanks!

Comment: I Just edited the post can you have a look at the picture I posted and a little description of what I trying to figure out.

Comment: @HardikGupta - please modify your question to include properly formatted text, not an image of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.